# How to read an updated value that has not been committed within a transaction?

Tags: java, postgresql, transactions, ebean

I'm using Avaje Ebean API to CRUD data from PostgreSQL DB. Here is my code:

```
import com.avaje.ebean.Ebean;
import com.avaje.ebean.Query;
import com.avaje.ebean.SqlQuery;
import com.avaje.ebean.SqlUpdate;
...

class Example {
    private void insertStockItem(PickingFieldProductItemDto dto, StockDao stockDao) {
        try {
            Ebean.beginTransaction();

            List<PickingFieldProductItem> productList = dto.getItemList();
            for(PickingFieldProductItem product : productList) {
                StockDto stockDto = buildStockDto(product);
                Stock stock = stockDao.getStockItem(stockDto.ID);
                // stock.Quantity is always 500 
                if(stock != null) {
                    if(stock.getQuantity().compareTo(product.getOutcomingQuantity()) == 0)
                        stockDao.deleteStock(stockDto);
                    else {
                        int updateQuantity = stock.getQuantity() - product.getOutcomingQuantity();
                        // updateQuantity = 300 and I will update this value to stock table
                        int identity = stockDao.updateStock(stockDto.ID, updateQuantity);
                    }
                }
            }

            Ebean.commitTransaction();
        } catch (BusinessException e) {
            Ebean.rollbackTransaction();
        } finally {
            Ebean.endTransaction();
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is:

At the 1st loop I get stock object and see the value of Quantity property is 500, then I update it with another value (300). The update statement ran successfully, I checked the `identity` var, it returns value 1.

But at the 2nd loop I get stock object again and now the value of Quantity property is still 500. My expectation is 300. Assumption that `productList` has only 2 elements.

Anyone can help me how to get the expected value? It's possible?

Thanks.

Comment: You *always* see uncommmitted work on the same transaction it was done on. You can *never* see uncommitted work from other transactions. You have no control over this. I'm not sure your explanation fits the behaviour.

Comment: I can read the updated value but uncommitted from other transaction by using `READ_UNCOMMITTED` Isolation level, but it's not match in my case, do you have any recommendation or suggestion to work around?

Comment: No, you can't, because PostgreSQL does not support `READ UNCOMMIITTED`. In this case you need to either use the same database connection for both queries, or you need to wait for one transaction to commit before starting the next one.

Comment: Yes, thanks for your advice. I also looked at one of my previous project, there is a same scenario with my current project, but it works, I can make sure because it was re-tested and released to customer. The major different is that project use Seasar2(jdbcManager class) to communicate with DB (also PostgreSQL) and transaction is controlled by `javax.transaction.UserTransaction` interface. I'm investigating how does it worked regardless of `READ UNCOMMIITTED` doesn't support by PostgreSQL as you said.